# Index in tkinter.Text.insert

Tags: python, tkinter-text

Why I have an error *bad text index "1"* in

```
text.insert(1, "Hello world")
```

but

```
text.insert(1.0, "Hello world")
```

works fine?

Answer (score 0):

The function doesn't take an Integer as an Input but a Double value. That's why it works with 1.0 but not with 1. You could also use the string "insert" instead of 1.0, they both to the same thing.

Comment: But what the reason to have a double index? What could mean the index 1.1 (it works)? That's a point!

Comment: @Dmitry 1.1 means first line the first character. so 1.0 means first line 0th character

Comment: but math.pi is also ok! What could it mean? And how to write 1st line 10th character?